# Fancybox 3: position the iFrame in the top of the viewport?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

How to position the iFrame in the top of the viewport? 20 pixels down?

Here is my Fancybox code:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  iframe : {
    preload: false
  },
  .....
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content (except images) is centered using CSS only, therefore it would be something like this:

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `margin: 20px` should be `margin: 20px !important`. Otherwise, it will not work.